# Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token is expired" in Asp.Net core Web APi with Angular 6 Azure ad

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, authorization, token

I was facing an token expire issue inconsistently in my Wep App which has front end in angular 6 and backend in C# asp.net core web api project and I am using azure ad for login process so now I am refreshing the token from front end when I refresh token silently after expired old token but then my back end api does not work it give me below error

Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token is expired"

below code show how I am refreshing the token in fronted and its refreshed successfully but now sure what I do for back end

public completeAuthentication(): void {

```
    this._adal.handleWindowCallback();
    if (this._adal.userInfo.authenticated === false) {
        this._adal.acquireToken(this._adal.config.loginResource).subscribe(token => {
            this._adal.userInfo.token = token;
            if (this._adal.userInfo.authenticated === false) {
                this._adal.userInfo.authenticated = true;
                this._adal.userInfo.error = '';
            }
        }, error => {
            this._adal.userInfo.authenticated = false;
            this._adal.userInfo.error = error;
            this._adal.login();
        });
    }
```

}

Comment: Can please check the fiddler traces in which refresh token is passing to the web API request

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this question

Comment: @SruthiJ, yes I have checked with fiddler traces but nothing found, we changed some settings in azure active directory and its works partially but we still have some issue
Thanks for your help